# Double slit: Does human attention, such as meditation change the outcomes of the double slit experiment

Tags: double-slit-experiment, biophysics, observers

From Dean Radin's article published in Physics Essays, the abstract states:

Abstract: A double-slit optical system was used to test the possible role of consciousness in the
collapse of the quantum wavefunction. The ratio of the interference pattern’s double-slit spectral
power to its single-slit spectral power was predicted to decrease when attention was focused toward
the double slit as compared to away from it. Each test session consisted of 40 counterbalanced
attention-toward and attention-away epochs, where each epoch lasted between 15 and 30 s. Data
contributed by 137 people in six experiments, involving a total of 250 test sessions, indicate that on
average the spectral ratio decreased as predicted (z=-4:36, p=6·10-6
). Another 250 control
sessions conducted without observers present tested hardware, software, and analytical procedures
for potential artifacts; none were identified (z=0:43, p=0:67). Variables including temperature,
vibration, and signal drift were also tested, and no spurious influences were identified. By contrast,
factors associated with consciousness, such as meditation experience, electrocortical markers of
focused attention, and psychological factors including openness and absorption, significantly
correlated in predicted ways with perturbations in the double-slit interference pattern. The results
appear to be consistent with a consciousness-related interpretation of the quantum measurement
problem.  2012 Physics Essays Publication. [DOI: 10.4006/0836-1398-25.2.157]

Here is the article:
http://www.deanradin.com/papers/Physics%20Essays%20Radin%20final.pdf

Has there been other experiments that verify his conclusions? This seems very interesting.

Comment: What are $z$ and $p$? Also, in which way had the observers access to the course of the trials? What they did? Did they see in some way the particles beams at any step before hitting the detectors? And why the predictions disfavored the sharpness of the fringes? Why not oppositely?

Comment: z is the standard score of the spectral ratio R. R is the ratio between the double slit interference spectrum power and the diffraction spectrum power. p is the one-tailed probability associated with z.
Once a test session was under way, the computer synthesized
voice instructions directed the participants’
attention toward or away from the optical system in 15 s
epochs. A single test session consisted of 40 such epochs
presented in a counterbalanced order. The participants just sat in a room.
http://www.deanradin.com/papers/Physics%20Essays%20Radin%20final.pdf

Comment: $\triangle_R$ looks like it might be a reliable measure, but the calculation of the reported $z=(\triangle_R-\mu_R)/\sigma_R$ statistic looks fishy. The expectation value of $\mu_R$. the mean of the "permuted average", is itself 0 for _any_ results, it only depends on the choice of the 5000 random shift values. So it can't possibly be meaningful. The statistics only look less meaningful from there.

Answer (score 2):

No. In fact, in general the collapse of the wavefunction is *not* consciousness-dependent.

A good example would be using quarter-wave rotators. That sounds like a mouthful of jargon, but you need to understand that the light coming through the slits has some *polarization* which usually has to be modeled as having two "linearly independent" components; in this case we'd say that the light is either "waving" up-down or left-right. 
We can "select" one or the other with a polarizing filter, which only lets light going one direction through.

Let's ignore these filters for now, but we'll come back to them. Polarizing filters are only one of our tricks! We can also *rotate* the polarization by a certain predictable amount. In this case, a "quarter-wave plate" will rotate it by 45 degrees in one or the other direction.

We can rotate the left slit by +45 and the right slit by -45, so that they are at 90 degrees and therefore completely incompatible. When we do this, *the interference pattern vanishes*. It vanishes as if the polarization were "observed", even though that polarization started out in an unknown state and ended up being lost to history and no conscious observer is paying any attention to the relevant variables. It is merely enough that you *could* insert two polarizing filters to determine "which way" the photon came from, that causes the photon to "pick a side".

So in that simple quarter-wave-plate example, the premise of the article is bunk (and that's confirmed by a follow-up article in the same journal, commenting on that article, by Massimiliano Sassoli de Bianchi).

It actually gets worse. This is the opening setup for an experiment known as the (possiby delayed-choice) quantum eraser experiment. In this experiment, the main difference is that the photon which comes into the double-slit experiment is generated with a quantum-entangled polarization to another photon which we send down a long fiber-optic cable. The light which enters the double-slit experiment does, indeed, still display the double-slit effects and then these effects are still destroyed by the quarter-wave plates.

However, you can then do something interesting: measure the polarization of the entangled photon -- the one that went down the fiber-optic cable. You simply send it through a polarizing filter. If that filter is up-down or left-right then you will see no interference patterns, but if it is diagonal, you can cause the interference pattern to emerge. So just by fiddling with a knob on the other end of your lab, with no conscious intervention to figure out the path of the particle, we are creating or destroying interference patterns in the double-slit experiment.

These experiments have in fact been done and the results are in agreement with standard quantum theory, having nobody in particular observing the polarizations and having a relativistic separation between the fiber-optic photon's polarizer and the double-slit experiment.